# React with Typescript : Properties defined in FC (Functional Component) not accessible from parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, resharper, visual-studio-2019

I have defined a property type for a functional component. However the properties are not accessible/visible to the parent components.

The created FC is below

```
/* declare properties */
type EcmTextBoxProps = {
     value: string; 
}

const ecmTextBox: React.FC<EcmTextBoxProps> = (props: EcmTextBoxProps) => {
    return (
    <div>
        {props.value}
    </div>
  );
}
export default  ecmTextBox
```

When I'm try to provide values to the defined properties, they are not accessible/visible to the parent component.

The properties of this component are not listing in the intellisense.

Please see the below image (I don't see the properties).

[image]

Even I tried with class components, ended with same results.

Seems to me something wrong with Resharper and VS configurations but I'm not sure.

I have set the latest version of Typescript to 3 in Resharper (That's the max value they have in their selection list) also 3.6 in VS.

There could be something I missed in configuration? Please let me know what I've missed.

The tsconfig.json's setup is as below:

[image]

Please note that I'm using following frameworks and tools;

**React: 16.12.0**

**Typescript: 3.7.5**

**Visual Studio 2019**

**Resharper Ultimate 2019.2.2**

Appreciate your prompt reply in this regard.

Please contact me should you require further information.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get that error myself, using VSCode. I'm not sure this will be a fix in your case, but what I do is force quitting VSCode and reopening it. That usually fixes the errors with intellisense not picking up the props as expected.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I tried many times closing and reopening the VS but no luck. I think this is something to do with Resharper or VS configuration but dont know where to look. I dont have this issue with VS Code
Code